# error: Could not find a declaration file for module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic' angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9, ckeditor5

I want to use ckeditor in angular 9, I followed instructions in https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html
but it shows an error where I import '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic':

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'. 

'a:/repositories/BasimStore/source/Web/Frontend/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-build-classic` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';`
```

[image]

I have both "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.2.3" and "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^20.0.0" in package.json but still it shows the error.
I could't find index.d.ts in ckeditor5-build-classic folder. How should I fix this error?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Add **typings.d.ts** file in your project root or any folder

add following code into the typing file

```
declare module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic' {
    const ClassicEditorBuild: any;

    export = ClassicEditorBuild;
}
```

that's it angular will automatically detect typings  and compile it as dependency this will solve the issue its also sugggested in official CKEDITOR page: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html

[image]

Directory Structure

[image]

Comment: In additon to above suggestion do below steps:

add import to the component where that issue was occurring in say **x.component.ts**

    import * as ClassicEditorBuild from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

    export class x implements OnInit { public Editor = ClassicEditorBuild;constructor() { }  ngOnInit(): void {}}

Finally, add below code in your **x.component.html**

    <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor>

Comment: I added it to the module that had the '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic' import and it worked

Comment: Brilliant. I had the same issue and your suggestion worked. Big ups

Comment: didn't work in root, had to use `src`

Answer (score 6):

I have the same issue with angular 8
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.2.3",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^19.0.2",

Edit: I found this solution: edit your TypeScript Config file (tsconfig.json) and add a new key value pair as

```
"noImplicitAny": false
```

Comment: Not really a solution noImplicitAny is there for a reason to enforce types

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, too.

[image: error picture]

After running this command:

```ts
npm i --save-dev @types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-build-classic
```

The errors disappeared immediately.

Comment: My watchdog couldn't find CKEditorError to import. This resolved my issue.

Comment: tried on ng17. doesn't do jack

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still interested there is community support for TS.
All you need to do is to update your package.json with entries like:

```
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-core": "^27.0.13",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^27.0.0",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-essentials": "^27.0.4",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-paragraph": "^27.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript can't find a declaration file and is complaining about the implicit/inferred type of "any".

You can disable the rule as noted by @khaled (the "nuclear" option - the rule is disabled globally).

A better workaround is to explicitly define the type of ClassicEditorBuild as "any" in a typings.d.ts file as described here: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/issues/70#issuecomment-513827165

That worked for me when upgrading to CKEditor5 with Angular 11.0.5 and Typescript 4.0.2

Answer (score 0):

According of https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/angular.html#using-a-custom-ckeditor-5-build

**First**:

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular
```

**Second:**
Install one of the CKEditor 5 predefined builds or create a custom one.
e.g:

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

Install all the required peer dependencies:

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-core @ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine @ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils @ckeditor/ckeditor5-watchdog
```

at last add the following to `tsconfig.json`

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es2015"
    // other options
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Step1) First Identify the error and Read The error carefully

Step 2)  they give new one to install ckeditior try it for Ex: like these npm

```
install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

Step3) Even though its not work

Step4) Type **ClassicEditor below** import statements they give option where to import
then you choose your ClassicEditor should be imported  **@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic**

Comment: Jalaleddin is actually missing the types definition which can be achieved from the following npm command.

npm i --save-dev @types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-build-classic

Comment: Yes but i given steps as sudo steps not exactly pin to pin i have not mention