# Angular build fails with ckeditor - Getter and setter accessors do not agree in visibility

Tags: angular, typescript, types, ckeditor, getter

I tried to install ckeditor5-angular and ckeditor5-build-classic according to
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/angular.html .
When Building, I got the error message:

```
Error: node_modules/@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-ui/src/editableui/editableuiview.d.ts:7:9 - error TS2379: Getter and setter accessors do not agree in visibility.

7     get _hasExternalElement(): boolean;
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-ui/src/editableui/editableuiview.d.ts:8:19 - error TS2379: Getter and setter accessors do not agree in visibility.

8     protected set _hasExternalElement(newValue: boolean);
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

editableuiview.d.ts:

```
import { Locale } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils";
import View from "../view";

export default class EditableUIView extends View {
    isFocused: boolean;
    name: string;
    get _hasExternalElement(): boolean;
    protected set _hasExternalElement(newValue: boolean);

    constructor(locale: Locale, editingView: View, editableElement?: HTMLElement);
}
```

Now what I could do is remove the portected from the setter but this change will not be permanent since it is a generated file in node_modules.

I have already created a typings.d.ts file which is recommended here: [error: Could not find a declaration file for module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic' angular 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62690188/error-could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-ckeditor-ckeditor5-build-c)

How could I fix this error permanently?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: use quill instead.  From my experience it is a lot easier to work with in angular. https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: I have uninstalled the types package for ckeditor and it was working without it after that.